# Como puedo pasarle el id de una tabla a otra sin que sea por request?

Tags: laravel-7

Buenas estoy intentando cargar un contacto a mi base de datos y una columna de mi base de datos es id_account, pero este campo no se tendria que pasar por request mediante un formulario sino que, debe asignarse automaticamente a través de la relación de mi tabla:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('id_account');
$table->foreign('id_account')->references('id')->on('customers');
```

Entonces yo en mi metodo store quiero cargar los siguientes datos:

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $contact = new Contact();
        $contact->name = $request->name;
        $contact->lastname = $request->lastname;
        $contact->id_account = Customer()->id;
        $contact->idOwner = Auth::user()->id;
        $contact->position = $request->position;
        $contact->mobile_no = $request->mobile_no;
        $contact->email = $request->email;
        $contact->save();
        Session::flash('success');
        return redirect()->route('contact.view');
    }
```

Pero estoy pasando:

```
$contact->id_account = Customer()->id;
```

Intenté tambien haciendo:

```
$contact->id_account = Customer::get('id');
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[{"id":1}]' for column `axis`.`contacts`.`id_account` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `contacts` (`name`, `lastname`, `id_account`, `idOwner`, `position`, `mobile_no`, `email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Mateo, Ghidini, [{"id":1}], 1, pasante, 12345678, mateo.ghidini@hotmail.com, 2021-08-04 17:05:47, 2021-08-04 17:05:47))
```

Que claramente no funciona. Como puedo hacer yo para que se me asigne en ese campo el id de la tabla customers mediante a la relación que mostre más arriba?